# Is USM lens suitable for static photos on canon 550d?

Tags: canon, canon-550d

I am looking to upgrade the lens on my canon 550d. An EF-S 18-135mm f/3.5-5.6 seems to be an all rounder for my needs. But i am thinking if there is any compatibility issue or such with a USM compared to an STM lens with the specific camera model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do higher end lenses use USM instead of STM?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59152/why-do-higher-end-lenses-use-usm-instead-of-stm)

Comment: Voting to close as a dupe because the answer of that question should show the pro's and con's of each well enough for you to make a purchase decision. If not, please edit your question to include why the linked one's answers do not provide you what you need. Thanks!

Comment: Basically i was hoping to clarify if there will be any compatibility issue with the 550d on the USM or STM lens.

Comment: Any EF-S or EF lens should work on your camera regardless of features such as USM/STM. Any competent camera retailer would be able to verify compatibility with a specific lens before you order as well.

Comment: Ah okay. That is awesome thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Canon EF or EF-S lens made since the EOS system was introduced in 1987 is fully compatible with your EOS Rebel T2i/550D. This is true regardless of whether the lens in question uses a "micro-motor", USM, or STM to move the lens' focussing elements.

For the differences and advantages/disadvantages of using each type of lens, please see:

- [Why do higher end lenses use USM instead of STM?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/59152/15871)
- [What is the difference between STM and USM in a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88390/15871)
- [What is Nano USM and how does it compare to an STM or USM lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/74876/15871)